# Connecting to cloud cassandra using python cassandra driver

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

How to create a Cassandra key space in predix cloud and make operations like create , insert, Update and select Operations?

Comment: have you tried any thing. if yes please post it here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to port 9042 (CQL protocol port) you can make a direct connection and perform any operation like normal. Where the actual nodes live doesn't matter. To ensure the lowest latency, you'll want the clients as close to the cluster nodes as possible.